# CSS background-color rgba. Bug in Android?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, android-webview

When I try to use `background-color: rgba(233, 233, 227, 0.72);` on a mobile device (or Tablet) with Android, a problem occurs:

[image: screen capture]

As you can see in the picture above, there is a horizontal line between the two divs. This problem only appears on Android devices: Android or Chrome browser.
On a desktop computer this code works fine.

If you want to try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/karmany/1y10cn0j/

Is this a bug on Chrome and Android browser?

Code:

```css
.bckg {
    background-color: blue;
}

.div-top, .div-bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(233, 233, 227, 0.72);
    background-clip: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bckg">
    <div class="div-top"></div>
    <div class="div-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it happen too if you instead use a hex color?

Comment: No. If you use a hex color this code works fine. The problem is rgba with alpha channel.

Comment: I tried this code on:
Aquaris E4.5 > Chrome 44.0.2403.133,
Sony Xperia > Chrome,
Tablet Samsung Galaxy > Android browser

Comment: Try adding transform:translateZ(0) to both divs. Someone with a similar problem found a solution in that.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've just tried "transform:translateZ(0)" and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely a bug in Chrome browser for Android. I've reported this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=524068